# wrong number of arguments error with deployment by capistrano

Tags: ruby, symfony, capistrano

deploy.rb

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock "3.8.2"

set :application, "wisdom"
set :repo_url, "ssh://app@extreammmm.jp/home/app/myGit/wisdom.git"

set :branch, 'master'
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/html/wisdom"

set :linked_files, %w{app/config/parameters.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{app/logs app/spool app/cache vendor web/vendor node_modules web/assets}
#somehow app/cache doesn't work...


set :format, :pretty
set :log_level, :debug
set :keep_releases, 3

after 'deploy:update_code' do
  capifony_pretty_print "--> Ensuring cache directory permissions"
  run "setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX #{latest_release}/#{cache_path}"
  run "setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX #{latest_release}/#{cache_path}"
  capifony_puts_ok
end

after 'deploy:starting', 'composer:install_executable'
#after 'deploy:updated', 'npm:install'   # remove it if you don't use npm
#after 'deploy:updated', 'bower:install' # remove it if you don't use bower
after 'deploy:updated', 'symfony:assets:install'
after 'deploy:updated', 'symfony:assetic:dump'
```

I want to change the permission of `app/cache` 777 after deployment.

At first I put `app/cache` in `linked_dirs` ,but somehow it doesn't work.

So now I am trying to change permission by acl and made this `deploy.rb`

however this code shows error.

`ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2+)`

I guess this error is related to `after 'deploy:update_code' do`, though I am not sure how to fix it.

please anyone helps me??

```
cap production deploy --trace
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
cap aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2+)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.8.2/lib/capistrano/dsl/task_enhancements.rb:10:in `after'
config/deploy.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.8.2/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:27:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.8.2/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:27:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.8.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/variables.rb:32:in `untrusted!'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.1_1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/delegate.rb:83:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.8.2/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.1_1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.8.2/lib/capistrano/application.rb:14:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.8.2/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/cap:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/cap:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => production
```

Thanks to @kiddorails

Finally I added these to deploy.rb, and the problem was solved.

```
after 'deploy:updated', :updated_cache do 
  on roles(:app) do
     execute :chmod, "-R 777 #{fetch(:deploy_to)}/current/#{fetch(:cache_path)}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Show the full stacktrace of error.

Comment: I added the full stacktrace error

Comment: Is there `config/deploy.rb:28` line?

Comment: I think it should be `after 'deploy:update_code', :updated_cache do .. end`

Comment: Sorry I have edited the deploy.rb like deleting comment out line and so on, for beeing easily seen. but it cause the confusion of error message line. I pasted all deploy.rb now and paste error message again.

Comment: @kiddorails I tried that but `Don't know how to build task 'deploy:update_code' (see --tasks)` error

Comment: I think in Capistrano 3, it should be `deploy:updated` instead of `deploy:update_code`. Check the available capistrano tasks by `cap -T`

Comment: @kiddorails Thanks, it works, so I updated my  article adding solution.